# I can't change a list to int with map function Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, int, python-3.3

My program ask the user to type 10 random numbers I'm using this code.

```
numbers = input("Type 10 numbers, separeted by spaces: ")
numberlist = list(numbers)
numberlist = map(int,numberlist)
print(numberlist)
```

but when the program is compiling I can type the 10 numbers but I get this message in the shell.

```
<map object at 0xb51a11cc>
```

Anyone knows what is the solution?. I'm using python 3.3 in ubuntu 13.04.

Thanks.

Comment: `list(map(int,numberlist))`, use `list()`. Note that `list(numbers)` will not do what you think it would do, use: `numbers.split()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` in Python 3.x returns a map object, not a list like it did in Python 2.x.  To fix this, put the map object in a list either here:

```
numberlist = list(map(int,numberlist))
```

or here:

```
print(list(numberlist))
```

Demo:

```
>>> lis = ['1', '2', '3']
>>> map(int, lis)
<map object at 0x01DE0F70>
>>> list(map(int, lis))
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

Also, you are going to want to do the below so it works (right now it will try to make all the spaces into integers, which will blow up):

```
numbers = input("Type 10 numbers, separated by spaces: ").split()
```